# Why should we not pass the input of the program in the printf statement?

Tags: c, printf

What are the security breaches possible ? or any attacks?

Answer (score 2):

Which argument of the printf function?

`printf("%s\n", untrusted_string);` is mostly OK, although if output is going to a terminal, and if the terminal responds to control codes, then it potentially could mess up the terminal settings beyond all recognition.

Obviously it also gets interesting when the output of your program is going to be used as executable code. It may not always be obvious to you that it is. For example, suppose you write a program that scans your web server logs and produces an HTML report listing all the URLs visited. Suppose further that I visit `http://example/<script>...</script>`. I get an error message, but the URL is still logged. If you've printed the input without modification, then you might be in for an educational evening when you review your report files. The user input needs to be sanitized somewhere along the line.

Echoing data that the user has supplied, back the same user, is somewhat safer. However, again in a web context, XSRF attacks are a common technique -- you might *think* that your users wrote the input themselves, when really they didn't, and so actually you're echoing some attacker's data back to the user. The same could apply even in command-line programs -- if the user supplies a file as a command-line argument, but the file (like my server log above) was written by an attacker, then printing parts of that file back to the user potentially has consequences the user never intended.

None of which is *necessarily* a reason not to do it. As ever in security, you can't say whether a particular action "is" or "isn't" secure, because it depends on the context in which that action occurs.

`printf(untrusted_string);` is definitely no good, since the string supplied might be "%s", with undefined behavior. You might think to yourself, "oh, well, it only *reads* where it shouldn't, what harm can that possibly do?" In which case you will eventually join the long list of people who've been surprised at the ingenuity which attackers show in combining multiple bugs to create a workable attack. Reading where you shouldn't clearly can lead to DoS, but also in combination with other issues could leak sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I messed up with the question somehow. It say: Why shouldn't we supply user provided data in user messages>

Answer (score 1):

A buffer overflow attack. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow