# Why shouldn't we supply user provided data in user messages? Any threats/attacks possible?

Tags: java, c, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should we not pass the input of the program in the printf statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008302/why-should-we-not-pass-the-input-of-the-program-in-the-printf-statement)

User messages can be via printf/messagebox...

Comment: Posting the same question after it has been closed is a waste of everyone's time.  Don't do it.  If you want your question answered, make it a **better** question.  For instance, make it intelligible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is concerning cross site scripting attacks.( assuming you are working in a Web Environment )

[You can read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)